# Memory usage decrease/Increase with respect to Dictionary<T,T> OR List<T>

Tags: list, c#-4.0, memory-management, dictionary

I have a project which operates huge amount of data. Major storage we used is  Dictionary. Infact thousands of dictionaries are created. After change it to List for keys and List for values (we implemented IDictionary ourselves) the memory usage decreased on about 30-40%.

Why?

Comment: What counts as "huge"? What is the element type here, and is it a struct or a class? How large is it? How many elements are there? If you could produce a short but complete program demonstrating a large difference, that would really help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And if you sort them and put them in an array, you can save another 30% of memory probably.

Features cost memory, you know?

`Dictionary<,>` gives you, for a price, a *O(1)* `Add()` and `TryGetValue()`

`List<>` gives you, for a smaller price, a *O(1)* `Add()` and, if sorted, a *O(logn)* `BinarySearch()`, but note that to keep it sorted you can't use `Add()`, you have to use `Insert()`, that is *O(n)*

The `T[]` gives you, for a even smaller price, if sorted, a *O(logn)* `BinarySearch()`. Technically you could have a *O(n)* insert, but you would have to do it manually (and the "real" cost would be a little bigger than the `List<>`'s one)

Now... if you want to know how `Dictionary<,>` uses your precious memory, you can look at the [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs)

There is this `struct`:

```
private struct Entry {
    public int hashCode;    // Lower 31 bits of hash code, -1 if unused
    public int next;        // Index of next entry, -1 if last
    public TKey key;           // Key of entry
    public TValue value;         // Value of entry
}
```

And there are two arrays, one of which uses this struct:

```
private int[] buckets;
private Entry[] entries;
```

So a `List<TKey>` + a `List<TValue>` is probably smaller than a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, because a `Dictionary<,>` has an additional `int[] buckets` plus an `int hashCode` and an `int next` for each element.

Note that the growing algorithm of `Dictionary<,>` and `List<>` are different. `List<>` grows by doubling its number of elements, while `Dictionary<,>` grows by doubling its number of elements and then finding a prime number greater than this. So `Dictionary<,>` grows a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago I did an analysis of `Dictionary` memory usage. In short, the overhead for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is 24 bytes per item. That's with the 64-bit runtime. See [More on .NET Collection Sizes](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/05/21/more-on-net-collection-sizes/) for more information.

`List<T>` overhead when storing reference types is 8 bytes per item: the amount of data required to hold a reference to the item in the list. You traded a single dictionary with overhead of 24 bytes per item for two lists with 8 bytes per item overhead each. So your total overhead is 16 bytes per item.

16 is 2/3 of 24. So you saved approximately 33%.

Likely what you encountered is the traditional size/speed tradeoff. The dictionary gives you O(1) lookup but uses more memory. Using two lists, you save memory but lookup is O(log n).